# Confusion over Regex greedy operator, and terminating character

Tags: java, regex, scjp

I'm studying up for the SCJP exam, and the following mock question caught me offguard. The explanation in the tool wasn't very good so I'm hoping the knowledgeable people of SO can explain it.

With the regex of `C.*L`, identify the words it would capture from `CooLooLCuuLooC`

I selected `CooL and CuuL`. My reason for this choice is because I believed it would look for a starting match of C, then take any character zero or more times until it finds an `L`, and then terminate.

However, the answer is actually `CooLooLCuuL`. I'm confused as to how the first 2 `L`'s make it through?

Could anyone please clear this up for me?

Thanks

Comment: You wrote the same answer twice...

Comment: Sorry, have fixed now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just one more possibly useful explanation:

The `.*` matches anything (except, by default, newlines!!!!), zero or more times - you understood that, generally. However, `.*?` also meets that definition. The difference is greediness...

- `.*` will match anything until it can't match anything else ('greedy' or 'eager')
- `.*?` will match anything until the following expression can be matched ('non-greedy' or 'reluctant')

Thus, `C.*L` will find a capital `C`, then match `ooLooLCuuLooC` with `.*`. It will then find it has to match a capital `L`. Being at the end of the string, that's not possible, so it goes to where it can match an `L`, forcing the `.*` to give up the characters `LooC` in order to do so. Result: `CooLooLCuuL`

If you were to use `C.*?L` it will find `C`, then match `o`, testing the next `o` for a match to `L`. This would fail, making it match `oo` and testing the next `L` for a match to `L`. This would succeed and it would return `CooL`.

A third option for matching either `CooL` or `CuuL` (that is any strings that start with `C` and end with `L`) would be `C[^L]*L`. This matches `C`, then any number of characters that are not a capital `L`, then a capital `L`.

Comment: why C.*?L would also match Cuul?! It looks like it would.

Comment: @despot -- not exactly _sure_ what your question is, but barring any typos, `Cuul` would not be matched, because it ends with `l` (lower-case letter el) -- if your question is "would `C.*?L` match `CuuL` in addition to `CooL`" then the answer is "yes, it would, if it were run in a way that got past the first match `CooL`; for instance, using a `matchAll()` type function or resuming search after the match `CooL` was found, possibly starting at index 4+". Incidentally, it would also match `C--L`, `CqwERtyL`, or even `C%@((*&^$%L`

Comment: sorry for the typo - "would" should have been "wouldn't".

Answer (score 2):

`C.*L` matches `CooLooLCuuL` because it's greedy. It will try to chew over as much as it can while still finding a match, until there's no more left of the string you're matching against to find a valid match. `C.*?L` is non-greedy and therefore matches `CooL`, since it will be satisfied when the first match is found. It will even leave off enough of the string for a second match `CuuL` to be found.

Answer (score 2):

This is because it's a `greedy search` and will match as many characters as possible and then backtrack until it finds a `L` character.

Here's a great resource to get more information in the matter: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html